# How do I push a user input into an array with React?

Tags: reactjs, arrays

I am a newbie to React and kinda JS. I've scoured this website/internet for an answer and can't find what I'm looking for. I have an array with some defined names to start. I'd like for the user to be able to input their own suggestions and add them to the array. Below is my code so far. The random name caller works just fine, but the input is what's really throwing me. It keeps saying addNewName and saveInput are defined/assigned a value but never used, and that this.state is undefined. Appreciate any help, thank you!

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default function App() {
  const names = [
    {nameCat: "Gibbis"},
    {nameCat: "Janet"},
    {nameCat: "Big Boy"},
    {nameCat: "Martin"},
    {nameCat: "Raccoon Baby"},
    {nameCat: "Bartholo-MEW"},
  ];

  const [activeCat, setActiveCat] = useState(0);
  
  const randomNames = e => {
    const len = names.length;
    setActiveCat(Math.floor(Math.random() * len));
  };

  function saveInput (e) {
    names(e.target.value);
  }

  const addNewName = (e) => {
    let { nameCat, input } = this.state;
    names.push(input);
    setActiveCat({nameCat: nameCat});
  };

return (
  <div class="container">
   <h1 class="gradient-text">let's name that cat!</h1>
    <h4>your cat's name is: <span class="catName">{names[activeCat].nameCat}</span></h4>
    <button onClick={randomNames}>new name!</button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input 
      type="text"
      onChange={this.addNewName}
      />
    <br/>
    <br/>
      <button onChange={(this.saveInput)}>add new name</button>
    </div>
);
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `this` inside React function components. And since `names` is going to change it should be another `state`. Try like below:

```js
const names = [
  { nameCat: "Gibbis" },
  { nameCat: "Janet" },
  { nameCat: "Big Boy" },
  { nameCat: "Martin" },
  { nameCat: "Raccoon Baby" },
  { nameCat: "Bartholo-MEW" }
];

function App() {
  const [cats, setCats] = React.useState(names);
  const [activeCat, setActiveCat] = React.useState(0);
  const [newName, setNewName] = React.useState("");

  const randomNames = (e) => {
    const len = cats.length;
    setActiveCat(Math.floor(Math.random() * len));
  };

  function saveInput(e) {
    setNewName(e.target.value);
  }

  const addNewName = () => {
    setCats((prevCats) => [...prevCats, { nameCat: newName }]);
    setNewName("");
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1 className="gradient-text">let's name that cat!</h1>
      <h4>
        your cat's name is:{" "}
        <span className="catName">{cats[activeCat].nameCat}</span>
      </h4>
      <button onClick={randomNames}>new name!</button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <input type="text" onChange={saveInput} value={newName} />
      <br />
      <br />
      <button onClick={addNewName}>add new name</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

nit: it should be `className` in JSX elements instead of `class` in HTML elements.

Comment: Wow, I was all over the place with combining class and function components! Thanks so much for this.

Just to make sure I have this correctly--in this section, you're updating the state of Cats by taking the prevCats and including them in a variable that pulls the newName from the user input. That input is pushed to nameCat, which is in the const names, which is passed through in const cats?

setCats((prevCats) => [...prevCats, { nameCat: newName }]);

Comment: Yes, that is right